# TeeChart RedCross Error Continued

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

This post corresponds to your answer on my previous post...

Before I upload a simple project for you, let me try something else: I noticed that when I swap the Points Series with a ColorGrid series the same thing happens, BUT, when I then (with the ColorGrid Series) use "MyColorGrid.YValues[gridPosition] = val" instead of MyColorGrid.Add(X, Y, Z) then it works. Is there a way I can use the Points Series in the same way, ie, allocate all the points the first time, and then just use XValues[idx] = x, and YValues[idx] = y to update the points? The problem seems to happen when I use the Add method, together with the Clear method. When I just update the values with XValues and YValues etc. the problem seems to be solved! The thing is, I can not get it to work on a Points Series...it was easy with the ColorGrid Series:

```
            for (int r = 0; r < 128; r++)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d < 128; d++)
                {               
                    MyColorGrid.YValues[d * 128 + r] = some_value;
                }
            }

            MyColorGrid.BeginUpdate();
            MyColorGrid.EndUpdate();
```

Question 1: How do I achieve the same for the Points Series?
Question 2: If I succeed, how do I clear/delete points, without again having to "Add(x, y)" them afterwards?
Question 3: Is this the best way to use BeginUpdate/EndUpdate? Whats the difference? In general, what are the differences between all the available update methods, and how do I choose the correct one? 
A few examples:

```
MyColorGrid.RefreshSeries
MyColorGrid.Repaint
MyTChart.Refresh
MyTChart.AutoRepaint
```

Regards

JD

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1: How do I achieve the same for the Points Series?**

I suggest you use a similar code as next that works in correct way when you update the points.

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points points1; 
Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1;
Random rnd; 
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
    this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
    tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
    tChart1.Height = 400;
    tChart1.Width = 500;
    tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
    points1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points(tChart1.Chart);
    rnd = new Random();
    InitializeChart();
}

private void InitializeChart()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        points1.Add(i, rnd.Next(100)); 

    }
    tChart1.Refresh();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        points1.XValues[i] = i+1;
        points1.YValues[i] = rnd.Next(100);

    }
    points1.BeginUpdate();
    points1.EndUpdate();

}
```

**Question 2: If I succeed, how do I clear/delete points, without again having to "Add(x, y)" them afterwards?**

I suggest you use the method SetNull() to make null the point as you don't want. You can do the same as next line of code:

```
points1.SetNull(3);
```

**Question 3: Is this the best way to use BeginUpdate/EndUpdate? Whats the difference? In general, what are the differences between all the available update methods, and how do I choose the correct one? A few examples:**

*About BeginUpdate/EndUpdate:*

The BeginUpdate method recalculates the function just one time, when finished adding points and the EndUpdate method is necessary used with .BeginUpdate to recalculate the function just once when finished adding points.
Therefore, you must use the both methods when you decide use BeginUpdate to update your series.

*About other methods:*

The  differences between methods are explained  by its definition that is found in help documentation and you can see in next lines:

**Series.RefreshSeries:** The RefreshSeries method notifies all dependent Series to recalculate their points again. Each Series has a DataSource property. When DataSource is a valid Series or DataSet component, Series get all point values from the DataSource and adds them as Series points. The RefreshSeries method forces the Series to Clear and get all points again from the DataSource component. The Refreshing process traverses the Series tree recursively

**Series.Repaint:** This Series method forces the whole Parent Chart to Repaint. You don't normally call Repaint directly. It can be used within derived TChartSeries components when changing their properties internally .

**TChart.Refresh:** Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself  and any child controls.

**TChart.AutoRepaint:** Use AutoRepaint false to disable Chart repainting whilst (for example) adding a large number of points to a Chart Series. This avoids repainting of the Chart whilst the points are added. AutoRepaint may be re-enabled, followed by a manual Repaint command when all points are added.

I hope will helps. If you have any questions please let me know.

Thanks,